# PHP count(): warning

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm making a simple CRUD single page application using PHP connected to a msqli database. All parts of the page work except for the "EDIT" function. It returns the warming "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable line 8"

```
 <?php 
include('server.php');
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = true;
        $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM eBook_MetaData WHERE id=$id");
        if (count($record) == 1 ) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $creator = $n['creator'];
            $title = $n['title'];
            $type = $n['type'];
            $identifier = $n['identifier'];
            $date = $n['date'];
            $language = $n['language'];
            $description = $n['description'];
        }
    }
?>
```

any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `mysqli_num_rows($record)` instead of `count($record)`.

Comment: [PHP delusion #5: Extensive use of the number of rows returned by a SELECT query](https://phpdelusions.net/top#num_rows)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows for checking numbers of row

Answer (score -1):

I have a feeling its your sql query too. Try this instead `$record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM eBook_MetaData WHERE id='$id'");`